# Подключение библиотеки SFML к Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml

Как можно подключить библиотеку SFML к Visual Studio таким образом, чтобы не приходилось подключать библиотеку к каждому проекту, а так, чтобы можно было спокойно использовать все заголовки/функции из SFML.

**UPD:** В одной статье я посмотрел как можно подключить библиотеку к проекту, я хочу сделать так, чтобы я мог создать любой проект и каждый раз не пришлось бы заново всё подключать, а чтобы уже всё было подключено и была бы возможность сразу всё использовать

Comment: В `Visual Studio` есть такая прекрасная штука, называется `nuget`, создаете новый проект, устанавливаете `nuget` пакет, все работает. И ничего не нужно подключать вручную.

Comment: Создайте шаблон проекта с SFML

Comment: @Croessmah каким образом?

Comment: @David https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2019